# Change resolution of image from 72 to 25 dpi in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to change the resolution of the image from 72 to 25 dpi using PHP?

is it possible?

Regards,

Salil Gaikwad

Comment: @Salil:  you have asked six questions and received eleven answers so far over two months, but you haven't accepted any.  How about rewarding those you found useful?

Comment: Just curious, what do you hope to achieve with changing the DPI? I cannot think of a reason for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible (*at least with PHP/GD, not sure about ImageMagik*), sorry.

However you can try mimicking it, lets say you want to create a 400x300 **25 dpi** image, here is the math:

**WIDTH**

```
72 -------- 400
25 -------- w = (25 * 400) / 72 (=) w ~= 139 pixels
```

**HEIGHT**

```
72 -------- 300
25 -------- h = (25 * 300) / 72 (=) h ~= 104 pixels
```

---

You create a new 139x104 **72 dpi** image, work with it and after you're done resize it to 400x300 pixels.

Comment: and how did you solve it, by using above calculations or other a way?

Answer (score 3):

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setresolution.php):

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->setResolution(25,25);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below line of code to convert image dpi from 72 to 25 dpi :

> $filename = "Enter path of the image which you want to use";

```
$image = file_get_contents($filename);
$image = substr_replace($image, pack("cnn", 1, 25, 25), 13, 5);
file_put_contents($filename,$image);
```