# PHP + GD2: How can change resolution of image?

Tags: php, gd2

I'm using gd2 lib to work with images. I need to change resolution of image, still I cant find a method for that in a list of methods. How that can be done?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled):

```
imagecopyresampled($resizedImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resizeWidth, $resizeHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight)
```

Comment: I see how an image can be resized with the method, still it's unclear how I can change resolution with it.

Comment: Look at this: [Change Resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121890/change-resolution-of-image-from-72-to-25-dpi-in-php)

Comment: So the solution is to scale down, and then scale up?

Comment: Yes. Either this or the other way around. I think thats the only way using GD